# SparkSql not supporting Date Format

Tags: java, apache-spark

I tried to use date file with sparkSql but its not working

Like for in example 
[javaSparkSqlExample](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/JavaSparkSQL.java)

I tried to add datecoloumn dob

In the Person class i added

setter and getter for dob as Date

when tried to execute

```
SELECT dob,name,age,count(*) as totalCount FROM Person WHERE dob >= '1995-01-01' AND age <= '2014-02-01';
```

Also tried using between also in the query instead of <= & >= as well

```
/Volumes/Official/spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop2$: bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local[4] try/simple-project/target/simple-project-1.0.jar 
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
2014-08-21 11:42:47.360 java[955:1903] Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore
=== Data source: RDD ===
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: class java.util.Date (of class java.lang.Class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still in pending, instead `Date` you can use `Timestamp` in `Person` class
[SPARK-2552](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2562)

> Spark SQL currently supports Timestamp, but not Date.

We are going tohave to wait for a while until the 1.2.0 version.

Details:

- Type: Improvement Improvement
- **Status: Open**
- Priority: Minor
- **Resolution: Unresolved**
- Affects Version/s: 1.0.1
- Fix Version/s: None
- Component/s: SQL
- **Target Version/s: 1.2.0**

Comment: seems its not supporting timestamp as well 
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: class java.sql.Timestamp (of class java.lang.Class)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext$$anonfun$getSchema$1.apply(JavaSQLContext.scala:140)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext$$anonfun$getSchema$1.apply(JavaSQLContext.scala:139)

am i missing something here

Comment: It supposed has been fixed since 1.0, I have been looking around and all support looks to be already incorporated (spark-1.0.2\sql\catalyst\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\sql\catalyst\types\dataTypes.scala) and (hive support), at least in version 1.0.2, but I have seen a suspect code (spark-1.0.2\sql\core\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\sql\column\ColumnType.scala) that does not incorporate references to Timestamp, even though you can find some patches and related commits. It looks it is not solved at 100% yet.

Comment: Refs: 
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/columnar
http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Timestamp-support-in-v1-0-td6850.html

Comment: I'm using spark 1.2.0 and I get the same exception, although the ticket is resolved. Tried also with 1.2.1 - same result.