# SparkSQL not supporting java.util.Date

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0, apache-spark-sql

Saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419412/sparksql-not-supporting-date-format), which implies it is fixed in spark 1.2.0. The [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2562) however talks about java.sql.Date.

Anyway, it is not working for me, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: class java.util.Date (of class java.lang.Class)
```

Here's a code example:

```
public class DateSparkSQLExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    List<SomeObject> itemsList = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(1);
    itemsList.add(new SomeObject(new Date(), 1L));
    JavaRDD<SomeObject> someObjectJavaRDD = sc.parallelize(itemsList);

    JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext(sc);
    sqlContext.applySchema(someObjectJavaRDD, SomeObject.class).registerTempTable("temp_table");
}

private static class SomeObject implements Serializable{
    private Date timestamp;
    private Long value;

    public SomeObject() {
    }

    public SomeObject(Date timestamp, Long value) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks, 
Lior

**EDIT 1:**

Maybe I rushed into posting this, because SparkSQL clearly states that the type for Date is java.sql.Date.
However, I would like to use the same bean for RDDs loaded from Cassandra and than registered to SparkSQL. Since in my C* model the data type is timestamp (which is mapped to java.util.Date), I can't really do it. 
As I see it, the only option to use the same model is change the C* type from timestamp to bigint, and it's a bummer.
Any ideas on how I can bridge this?

Comment: Any luck fixing this problem?

Comment: I actually don't remember the course of things since then... Anyway, there are a few cases in which I query for c* data and load it to spark sql. In all of them I load the data as long.